# How to change WSDL soap address location , in particular the context part of the url?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jboss-eap-6

Here i'm using java first approach to create web service.

I have exposed a web service using JAX-WS by using Endpoint api `Endpoint.publish(address,SampleWebService)` in JBOSS EAP 6.0 .

Whatever the value i provide for address field in the above publish method, it didn't matter i.e., i did not see the impact of that.
`SampleWebService` above is my  Web service implementation class.
After deploying the war file ,i will get WSDL file generated in the following location .

> %JBOSS_HOME%/standalone/data/wsdl/MyProjectName-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war

The above generated WSDL file contains soap:address location = "http://localhost:8080/MyProjectName-1.0-SNAPSHOT/SampleWebService?wsdl"/>

```
@webService(serviceName="SampleWebService")
public class SampleWebService {
    //Implementation specific logic
}
```

IS there any way that i can change the context i.e.,  in the soap address location to have MyProjectName instead of MyProjectName-1.0-SNAPSHOT so that the final soap address location will look like following

> soap:address location =
>   "http://localhost:8080/MyProjectName-1.0-SNAPSHOT/SampleWebService?wsdl"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

> All i wanted is to change the root context name so that i can provide
>   my own name instead of default war file name (complete name of the war
>   file excluding .war extension)

In order to change root context of the war file, i need to specify context name in jboss-web.xml file which reside in my web app's WEB-INF folder.

Thanks to this  [changing context root name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741633/remap-jax-ws-address) post which helped me in figuring out the solution for my case.

Now jboss-webapp.xml contains following content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="  
      http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee  
      http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
    <context-root>MyProjectName</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

The above change has helped me in getting the required soap address location url.
i.e., `<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/MyProjectName/SampleWebService?wsdl" />`